# Import CSV files using BCP to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, csv, import, bcp

My BCP command looks like this:

```
BCP azuredatabase.dbo.rawdata IN "clientPathToCSVFile" -S servername -U user@servername -P pw -c -t,-r\n
```

My CSV file is in {cr}{lf} format.

My CSV looks like this

```
125180896918,20,9,57.28,2020-01-04 23:02:21,282992,1327,4,2850280,49552
125180896919,20,10,57.82,2020-01-04 23:02:21,282992,1298,4,2850280,48881
125180896920,16,11,58.20,2020-01-04 23:02:21,282992,1065,4,2850280,48612
125180896921,20,12,69.10,2020-01-04 23:02:21,282992,515,4,2850280,10032
125180896922,20,13,70.47,2020-01-04 23:02:21,282992,1280,4,2850280,48766
125180896923,1,1,105.04,2020-01-04 23:02:21,,1296,4,2969398,49161
```

As you can see there are also empty fields.

My output looks like this

```
Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 547
```

So how do I correctly setup my command for BCP?

Comment: If you have BCP version 15.0.1000.34 or higher (check with `bcp /v`) then you should be able to use the new `-G` switch for Azure AD authentication, e.g.: `bcp bcptest in "c:\last\data1.dat" -c -t -S aadserver.database.windows.net -d testdb -G -U alice@aadtest.onmicrosoft.com -P xxxxx`

Comment: this does not work since we arent connecting with Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that your data is in CRLF format (that means \r\n). But your bcp command is told to look for a line terminator of \n (using the -r option).

I would have expected to see the first half of your actual CRLF line terminator of "\r\n" be split in half with the \r being included in your last column and the \n being found as the line terminator, but it look like BCP loaded no rows because it found no \n in your file.

I have not worked with Azure/BCP much, so maybe someone else knows how BCP for Azure would handle this, but the SQL Server version of BCP would still find your \n and then load the \r into your last column.

Either that or your line terminator is now what you think it is. Have you viewed the file with a text editor (not notepad, not wordpad... something that will show hidden characters like line terminators and tabs and such).

Usually, when BCP loads no rows (and there are rows in the file to load), it could be a mixup with line terminators.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad. It is indeed only {LF}.

So I have to use " -r '0x0A' "

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

However is it possible the set the locale in bcp ? 


Because I have this floats 57.28 but my SQL Server expects 57,28.